# Python: How do I correctly decrypt the text sent from my Ruby script?

Tags: python, rsa, pycryptodome

I am trying to encrypt text locally in Ruby and decrypt it on the server with Python.

I post the encrypted phrase like so:

```rb
require "base64"
require "openssl"

public_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new File.read './publickey.pem'
encrypted = public_key.public_encrypt "Hello everyone. This is a secret phrase."

uri = URI('#...')
params = { "passage" => Base64.encode64(encrypted) }

response = HTTParty.post(
              uri,
              :body => params.to_json,
              :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}
           )
```

My Python looks like this:

```py
    f = open('./privatekey.pem', 'rb') # generated with ruby (OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new 2048)
    private_key = RSA.importKey(f.read())
    f.close()

    return private_key.decrypt(encrypted)
```

This results in the error:

```
raise NotImplementedError("Use module Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP instead")
NotImplementedError: Use module Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP instead
```

So, I use `PKCS1_OAEP`:

```py
    #...

    cipher_priv = PKCS1_OAEP.new(private_key)
    decrypted = cipher_priv.decrypt(encrypted)
```

This results in the error:

```
raise ValueError("Incorrect decryption.")
ValueError: Incorrect decryption.
```

<strike>…and I'm sent round in circles.</strike> If not `PKCS1_OAEP` what is the correct decryption?

How do I decrypt the text sent from Ruby to the Python server?

Comment: Why circles? The incorrect description message doesn't tell you to go back to the not implemented one. So there are no circles here

Comment: Don't forget in Python it's often easier to use [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) than to fuss around with closing it manually, as in `with open(...) as f:`

Comment: You may want to look at what you're encrypting it with, as Ruby's defaults might not match up with what Python's expecting here. Are you decoding the Base64 correctly?

Comment: Post a [mre]. Anyway, research enough. It's obvious you encrypted with RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 algorithm, but decrypted with RSAES-OAEP algorithm. See [RFC 8017](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017). And don't use RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 because it's weak.

Comment: Use a symmetric algorithm. RSA is not normally used for encryption of data except to exchange encryption keys. The typical use case for RSA is creating hashes of data.

Comment: @John Hanley, FYI, RSAES-OAEP is fine for encrypting a small message. And a symmetric cipher alone cannot be used when you don't want to distribute the key with the client(even in an obfuscated form).

Comment: @relent95 you just reworded my comment.